# Why is my Spring Data JPA query 8 times slower than Node.JS + oracledb?

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, express, spring-data-jpa

I have created two basic projects to compare frameworks. When doing development on a recent project at work I noticed that the queries were running extremely slow when using Spring Data JPA.

I set up a small experiment to test NodeJS vs Spring Boot in order to find out if it was the database or the framework.

`SELECT * FROM v$version;`

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

This database is located 400 miles away at another facility, introducing around 60-80ms of network latency.

```
-------------- -------- ------------ 
ID             NOT NULL NUMBER       
AR                      VARCHAR2(10) 
MOD_TIME                DATE         
MOD_UID                 VARCHAR2(10) 
ACTIVE_IND              VARCHAR2(1)  
WORK_ID                 NUMBER
```

There are 4533 records in this database in our test environment. We have approximately 9000 in production. This experiment will be run using the test environment.

**Spring Setup:**

start.spring.io and select Web ,JPA, Oracle Driver, lombok

Created a entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_test")
@Data
public class TTest implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3305605889880335034L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "AR")
  private String ar;

  @Column(name = "mod_time")
  private Timestamp modTime;

  @Column(name = "mod_uid")
  private String modId;

  @Column(name = "active_ind")
  private String activeInd;

  @Column(name = "work_id")
  private Integer wid;

}
```

and then a simple repository to run the findAll() query

```
@Repository
public interface TTestRepo extends JpaRepository<TTest, Integer> {}
```

and finally a controller

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    TTestRepo repo;

    @GetMapping("/testDb")
    public List<TTest> testDb(){
        return repo.findAll();
    }

}
```

I used application.properties to connect to the databse

```
spring.datasource.url=blah
spring.datasource.username=blah
spring.datasource.password=blah
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

**NodeJS setup**

Just a simple express app with oracledb installed.

```
const express = require('express')

var oracledb = require('oracledb')
oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    //removed for obvious reasons
  },
  function(err, connection) {
    console.log('trying to connect...')
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return
    }

    global.connection = connection
  }
)

global.transformResults = function transformResults(result) {
  let finalResults = []
  let obj = {}

  result.rows.forEach((row) => {
    result.metaData.forEach( (meta, j) => {
      obj[meta.name] = row[j]
    })
    finalResults.push(obj)
    obj = {}
  })
  return finalResults
}

// Create express instnace
const app = express()

// Require API routes
const users = require('./routes/users')

// Import API Routes
app.use(users)

// Export the server middleware
module.exports = {
  path: '/api',
  handler: app
}
```

users.js is just a router or rest endpoint where I run my query

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const router = Router();

router.get("/testDb", async function(req, res, next) {
    connection.execute(
      "SELECT * from t_test",
      function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err)
          return
        }
        res.json(transformResults(result));
      }
    )
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Benchmark tests**

For Spring Data JPA I did this benchmark test

```
/**
 * @author Jake Perkins on 11/20/2019
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BenchMark {

    @Autowired
    TestController controller;

    @Test
    public void benchmarkDb(){
        int testLength = 100;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < testLength; i++){
            controller.testDb();   //Measure execution time for this method
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long durationInMillis = (endTime - startTime);   //Total execution time in milliseconds
        BigDecimal averageInSeconds = BigDecimal.valueOf(durationInMillis/testLength).movePointLeft(3);
        System.out.println(averageInSeconds);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
23.463
```

NodeJS benchmarks were calculated similarly using a difference between start time in milliseconds and end time in milliseconds.

**Experiment results**

I have run the query 100 times in both environments and have gathered the following average times.

Spring Boot: 23.4 seconds

NodeJS : 2.9 seconds

Oracle SQL Developer : 2.6 seconds

Spring boot is taking roughly 8 times longer than node JS when gathering 4533 records (in my specific case). Why?

Comment: Can you please provide the code by which you determined the benchmark times

Comment: Have you tried with straight JDBC? Spring and Hibernate use reflection/proxying to transform the data back. Also, was this on a single query or have you tried running the query multiple times within the same JVM (to ensure warm-up)?

Comment: @DanW No, I have not tried straight JDBC, but this question is specifically related to spring data JPA. Yes, I have run this query multiple times within the same JVM. This query is actually a big part of my application I'm creating at work. I have run this query hundreds (if not thousands) of times. This experiment was inspired by the fact that I wait for a long time each time I test my applications interface.

Comment: Try sharing the benchmarking code for Spring Data. The behavior is not at all normal in my experience.

Comment: @Pedro I have edited my post to include the java benchmark testing code

Comment: @Blake I have edited my post to include the java benchmark testing code

Comment: There is no cache nor hydration on nodejs. while there is in standard jpa setup. But still should not generate that much of a delay.

Comment: For starters, I would let the engine warm up a bit. Try to run the query a few times before the actual benchmarking for-loop. Just to be sure the delay is not concentrated on the first query due to metadata loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought is a difference in array fetch size or prefetch size.  This can have a big impact on multi-row query performance over WANs.

From [Oracle® Database JDBC Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/resultset.html#GUID-BD27B43E-525F-44C4-973F-18D2BB8BA007):

> By default, when Oracle JDBC runs a query, it retrieves a result set
>   of 10 rows at a time from the database cursor

From [node-oracledb Documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propdbfetcharraysize):

> This property sets the size of an internal buffer used for fetching
>   query rows from Oracle Database. Changing it may affect query
>   performance but does not affect how many rows are returned to the
>   application.
>
> The default value is 100.

You can easily change `oracledb.fetchArraySize` to 10 in the Node.js app and see if performance drops to Spring's.

And you can increase the size to see if you get better performance.

Comment: This was it! I created a ```DataSource``` bean in spring boot with the following properties added. ```properties.put("defaultRowPrefetch", "100");
        properties.put("defaultBatchValue", "100");``` my average time went from 30 seconds to 3.8. One last question for you... I have tested this with 1000 as the setting and was able to achieve 2.1 seconds. Are there are repercussions for setting this value so high? We expect this table to grow many times it's current size and want to keep the select queries very fast.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Spring Boot, but I'd expect the performance of all the options to be closer than what you're seeing. Does Spring Boot create a connection pool by default? If not, you should look into that.

Also, the Node.js code is reusing a single connection. You should be using a connection pool instead. See this series on creating a REST API with Node.js and Oracle Database for more info:
https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Comment: Yes, Spring Boot uses HikariCP as the default connection pool. Thank you for the reference as you can tell I'm new to NodeJS Rest API's. I was just curious to see if the grass was greener on the other side. Would I see a performance difference in NodeJS by using a connection pool?

Comment: The performance wouldn't be better, per se, but connection pools offer all kinds of features that you don't get if you simply pass around a connection. How else would you create transaction boundaries, queue requests when a connection is in use, etc.? Don't forget that simple `execute` calls are just the start. There are many types of calls, such as streaming large result sets and LOBs that require many subsequent calls to complete.

Comment: And a connection pool will make the app scalable.